# JCrop How to crop image by dragging it behing a div (like facebook cover)

Tags: jquery, image, crop, jcrop

I have used [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) extensively but I want to crop the image in much similar way the Facebook uses for cropping its cover image.

So, I want a div to be of some fixed size wherein the background to hold a draggable image of its original size, which the user drag and find the suitable visible region to be cropped.

From what I have learnt, in JCrop, the original image is of fixed size and draggable region moves over it which you want to be cropped.I just want the opposite. The image to be draggable and selection region to be fixed.

Is there a way to do it using JCrop?

**EDIT:**
Since it's been some time I posted the answer, [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128050/jcrop-how-to-crop-image-by-dragging-it-behing-a-div-like-facebook-cover/25108478#25108478) helps in much better way. Please check that out

Comment: I would love to have a solution like this one @ashutosh did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @ademg : got any solution, please add here if you got any

Comment: @ashutosh : got any solution, please add here if you got any

Comment: ok since I can not get any good answers, I will now answer how I resolved my problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To crop images like in Facebook (dragging within an area) I'd strongly recomend using [Guillotine](//github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine) ([demo](//matiasgagliano.github.io/guillotine)).

It's a very lightweight plugin and allows to crop, zoom and rotate images. It also has touch support and it's responsive (fluid). It's perfect for Facebook like cropping and it's really easy to setup.

Comment: I need to send cropped image to API when clicked on SAVE button.

Answer (score 6):

I have been searching this for a while, While I got another great plugin- [JWindowCrop](http://www.tmatthew.net/jwindowcrop)

Also you can get plugin from the [repository](https://github.com/tybro0103/jWindowCrop.git).

It is benefitial for the fact that the plugin is quite simple and you can easily modify it as per your needs.

Here  is how I did it to match the crop area of facebook cover:

HTML:

```
<img id="target" class="crop" alt="" src="images/sample-cover.jpg" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.crop').jWindowCrop({
                targetWidth: 851, //Width of facebook cover division
                targetHeight: 315, //Height of cover division
                loadingText: 'Your Cover is uploading....',
                onChange: function(result) {
                    console.log("separation from left- "+result.cropX);
                    console.log("separation from top- "+result.cropY);
                    console.log("width- "+result.cropW);
                    console.log("Height- "+result.cropH);
                }
            });
```

You can modify the internal region if you are not satisfies with the plugin.

**NOTE**: Since the facebook cover is of width 851px only, the uploaded image and the cropper division must be of same width i.e 851px.

I have prepared a [DEMO](http://codepen.io/ashutosh2k12/pen/PZborP) here

**EDIT:**
Just in case if you noticed the text "Drag to reposition" in the crop area(top-left side) while you drag the image inside cover, you can mention you own text by changing this line of plugin:

```
 Line:34-   base.$frame.append('<div class="jwc_controls" style="position:relative;display:'+(base.options.showControlsOnStart ? 'block' : 'none')+';"><span class="dragger">Drag to reposition</span></div>');
```

I could not got time to add an option in the plugin to do so.

Comment: This plugin is great! Have you found a way to use it with a form? I need to crop an image before upload and I want also to keep the original version. I'm trying to modify bootstrap file-uploader to show two preview windows, one of them with jwindowscrop.

Comment: can you show me a fiddle or example of how are you using? Maybe I can then suggest some change. From what you told, I suggest you to use jquery `on` method to trigger the jwindowcrop function to enable cropping in the preview area.

Comment: [DEMO PAGE](http://media.dday.it/roby/jquery/robycrop) you can see my demo page. I don't know how to call my jWindowCrop function on "upload" event. If I launch it using the console it works!

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.. Great plugin.

Comment: JWindowCrop - how I can get cropped image?

I need a SAVE button and when click on SAVE button then cropped image need to send to server as banner image will be saved in server.

Answer (score 1):

upload image like facebook cover image use this plugin  [facebook-style-cover-image-reposition](http://w3lessons.info/2014/08/31/facebook-style-cover-image-reposition-using-jquery-php/)